# String Objects in Memory after Concating in C#

Tags: c#-4.0

I understand in C# that string is Immutable when I concat 2 strings a new object is created.
What happens to the previous objects in the memory?
Does GC remove the old object as soon as a new object is created?

Answer (score 1):

When you are modifying a value of the string, i.e. you are creating a new object which refers to that modified string and the old one becomes unreferenced.
Hence, if we are modifying the existing string continuously, then numbers of the unreferenced object will be increased and it will wait for the garbage collector to free the unreferenced object.
When garbage collector run it reclaim all unused memory occupied by unreferenced objects.

Comment: So when GC will remove Remaining objects?

Comment: You dont need to worry about this. In .Net CLR will handle this all things.
If you want to run GC then use  GC.Collect() method.

Check this link , This will help you.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/fundamentals